# How to get the row number where its ID is 'n' and rows are ordered by some column?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get the row number, knowing the row ID, smomething like this:

Get the row number (position) from `Table1` order by `Col1`, where this row `ID` is `263`

```
 ID |     Col0 |  v Col1 |    Col2
----|----------|---------|---------
258 |        R |       a |       7
262 |        A |       a |       8
277 |        C |       a |      29
263 |        R |       a |      30
202 |        A |       b |      13
219 |        D |       b |      14
  4 |        A |       c |      15
220 |        G |       e |      16
278 |        B |       e |       7
  9 |        P |       f |      18
```

Is there any way to achieve this

Answer (score 4):

I imagine you'll probably need a secondary ordering column, as `Col1` is not a unique value, however this should get you started.

```
WITH sampledata AS
(
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Col1) as row_num,
    ID,
    Col0,
    Col1,
    Col2
  FROM Table1
)

SELECT 
  row_num 
FROM sampledata 
WHERE ID = 263;
```